# How does Databind consume a DataReader

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

If I have a control on a page that has its Datasource set to a DataReader, does that control consume the reader at the time the Datasource is set, or does the datareader continue to exist until Databind has been executed?

What actually happens under the covers when Databind is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the Control, DataBind() will Bind the Data to the
Control. It does this by Iterating through the DataSource and create
the Html and other Controls that are needed.

For a DropDownList, DataBind() will create the ListItem for each
record in a DataSet or each Element in an ArrayList.

Later the Render method is call on the DropDownList, which returns the
Html for a Select tag. It also creates the Html for each ListItem by
returning Option tags inside the Select tag.

For a Label, DataBind() will set the Text to the value you pulled from
the Database (for example).

If you don't call DataBind() for the specific control, you can also
make sure that your DataSource is set for a control and call
Page.DataBind(). This will go through the Controls in the Page and
call all of the DataBinds for each Control.

Answer (score 1):

It should be consumed at the time DataBind is executed.

Answer (score 0):

What is the control doing with the datareader during databind? Does it copy it into its internal structures and dispose of the datareader then render?

If I have 10 controls on a page and set the datasource on each to a different datareader, then called page.databind, will the datareaders exist the entire time (from the point of creation until the point where the page.databind completes it's processing)?